# Angular: no me funciona el agregar a "carrito" de a mas de una cantidad

Tags: angular, crud

Soy nuevo en angular quería hacer una consulta... Quiero agregar a mi arreglo vacío a través de un button y un servicio de "carrito". Cuando quiero agregar un ítem solo me lo agrega, pero quiero agregar mas de un item por ejemplo cantidad = 2 y me sigue agregando de a "0"... No puedo darme cuenta del error, tampoco se si estoy incluyendo mal los servicios al ser nuevo en este tema se me complica darme cuenta de esos errores... ni saber donde esta mi error... Me podrían dar una ayuda?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Productos } from './product-list/Product';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
// Maneja la logica del carrito

export class ProductsCartService {


ShopList: Productos [] = [];


constructor() { }

  addToCart(item: Productos) {
  
    let items: Productos = this.ShopList.find((v1) => v1.Nombre == item.Nombre)!;
    if(!items) {
      this.ShopList.push({ ... item});
    } else {
      item.cantidad += item.cantidad;
    }
    console.log(this.ShopList);}}
```

Este es mi componente donde yo tengo mi arreglo con cosas y las muestro:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductsCartService } from '../products-cart.service';
import { Productos } from './Product';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-list',
  templateUrl: './product-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-list.component.scss']
})
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {


products: Productos [] = [{ 
Nombre: "Logitech G430",
Categoria: "Auricular",
Precio: 12000,
Stock: 2,
image: "assets/images/auricularlogitech.jpg",
clearance: false,
cantidad: 0,


},

{
  Nombre: "Razer Sylom",
  Categoria: "Teclado",
  Precio: 16000,
  Stock: 0,
  image: "assets/images/tecladorazer.jpg",
  clearance: false,
  cantidad: 0,

},

{
  Nombre: "Steelseries V90",
  Categoria: "Mouse",
  Precio: 12000,
  Stock: 2,
  image: "assets/images/mousess.jpg",
  clearance:true,
  cantidad: 0,



},

{
  Nombre: "Steelseries AK47",
  Categoria: "Auricular",
  Precio: 21000,
  Stock: 5,
  image: "assets/images/auricularss.jpg",
  clearance:false,
  cantidad: 0,


},

{
  Nombre: "Genius FIUM",
  Categoria: "Mouse",
  Precio: 4000,
  Stock: 51,
  image: "assets/images/mousegenius.jpg",
  clearance: true,
  cantidad: 0,



},
{
  Nombre: "Razer inalambric",
  Categoria: "Mouse",
  Precio: 42000,
  Stock: 0,
  image: "assets/images/mouserazer.jpg",
  clearance: false,
  cantidad: 0,



}

];
 
 



  constructor(private cart: ProductsCartService ) { 
    
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }







addToCart(item: Productos): void {
  this.cart.addToCart(item);
  item.Stock -= item.cantidad;
  item.cantidad = 0;
}




  

DownQuantity (item: Productos){

if (item.cantidad > 0)
  item.cantidad--;

  }


upQuantity(item: Productos){
if (item.cantidad < item.Stock)
  item.cantidad++;

  }

  maxReached(m: string){
    alert(m);

  }
}
```

Y este es mi HTML:

```
   <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of products" [ngClass]="{'clearance': item.clearance}">
            <td>{{item.Nombre | uppercase}}</td>
            <td>{{item.Categoria}}</td>
            <td><img class="img-thumbnail" [src]="item.image" [alt]="item.Nombre" width="100" height="100"></td>
            <td>{{item.Precio | currency}}</td>
            <td><span  *ngIf="item.Stock==0" class="badge text-bg-warning"> SIN STOCK </span></td>
            <td><app-input-number [cantidad]="item.cantidad" [max]="item.Stock" *ngIf="item.Stock" (maxReached)="maxReached($event)"></app-input-number></td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addToCart(item)"> Comprar </button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Muchas gracias espero ayuda... gracias!!

Comment: Prueba cambiando esto `item.cantidad += item.cantidad` por `item.cantidad += 1`

Comment: no funciona igual

Comment: Me ignora el input con la cantidad que ponga, por ejemplo pongo 5 y me cuenta como 1.

Comment: Esto está mal `item.cantidad += item.cantidad;` debe ser `items.cantidad += item.cantidad;`

Comment: Hola lobos gracias por contestar! Pero me sigue sin andar... yo pongo cantidad 3 en el input y me sigue contando la cantidad como 0... me estoy fijando en el console log.